# Add a User Control to DevExpress Menu Bar

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, user-controls, devexpress

i create my own User Control with C# .Net DevExpress. Now i can use this Control in all my projects, but i need to use it in a DexExpress.XtraBars.Bar. How can i take this? I just can use the baritems like Button, Check usw.

regards

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You **can't** use the UserControl within the BarItem ([Custom Controls on Toolbars](http://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/p/S20141.aspx)). But you can implement a custom editor and place it into the [BarEditItem](http://documentation.devexpress.com/#WindowsForms/clsDevExpressXtraBarsBarEditItemtopic). You can find the addition information in the [Custom Editors](http://documentation.devexpress.com/#WindowsForms/CustomDocument4716) help topic. For example you can subclass one of existing editors (for example, the ButtonEdit), and override the Painter and ViewInfo classes.

Please also review the following KB Article: [How to use a custom control in inplace mode in DevExpress containers](http://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/p/A128.aspx).

Answer (score 1):

Hard to say how to achieve it without knowing what kind of user control you made. But I think you can't add custom user control to bar, but you can create custom bar item. [Here](http://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/p/E2460.aspx) is an example. Or you could try to inherit `BarItem` class and then try to add to bar.